# How to validate parameter with inputParser in view of an already given required parameter

Tags: matlab

I have two required inputs, called **domain** and **distribution**, and two two optional parameter-value pairs: **grainCount**-integer value and **radius**-double value. The **distribution** must take a 1x4 vector and the **distribution** can be either 'uniform' or 'hex'. Until now, there is no problem. The **grainCount** is only meaningful if the **distribution** was set to 'uniform'. Similarly, the **radius** is meaningful if the **distribution** was set to 'hex'. What I want to do is to throw a warning if **radius** is provided with 'uniform' **distribution** or if **grainCount** is provided with 'hex' **distribution**. I was thinking of creating the validating functions as nested functions so that it can see the *inputParser* object and can extract its **distribution** value already given. The problem is that only the name of the given property can be seen, not its set value (i.e. either 'uniform' or 'hex'). How could I solve it? I prefer a solution with the *inputParser* class as it is powerful. Below is the attached code. I call it with `createRVE([0 1 1 2], 'hex', 'nGrain',3)`.

```
function out = createRVE(domain, distribution, varargin)
%% Process inputs
% Provide the callback functions for the input processing
validDistribution = {'uniform', 'hex'};
validateDistribution = @(x) any(validatestring(x, validDistribution));
    function TF = validateDomain(domain)
        TF = false;
        if ~isnumeric(domain)
            error('domain must have numeric type.');
        elseif ~(isequal(size(domain),[1 4]) || isequal(size(domain),[4 1]))
            error('domain must have the size 1x4 or 4x1.');
        else
            TF = true;
        end
    end

    function TF = validateGrainCount(nGrain)
        TF = false;
        if ~isnumeric(nGrain)
            error('nGrain must have numeric type.');
        elseif ~isscalar(nGrain)
            error('nGrain must be a scalar.');
        else
            TF = true;
        end
        % Check if the distribution is 'uniform'
        % pseudocode: if p.distribution has value 'hex'
        %                warning('nGrain is defined only for uniform distribution.');
        %             end
        % How can I obtain that the distribution is 'hex' or not?
    end

% Parse the inputs with the inputParser class
p = inputParser;
% Two required inputs: the tesselated domain and the distribution of seeds
addRequired(p, 'domain', @validateDomain);
addRequired(p, 'distribution', validateDistribution);
% Add parameter name-value pairs
addParameter(p, 'nGrain', 10, @validateGrainCount)
% Parse it
parse(p, domain, distribution, varargin{:});
end
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say `The problem is that only the name of the given property can be seen, not its set value (i.e. either 'uniform' or 'hex')`. `p.Results` returns a structure that has this information.

Comment: @excaza Yes, p.Results returns but only _after_ calling the parse method. I was thinking of extracting this information before calling the parse method. However, as written by **hoogamaphone** in his answer, this check cannot be done merely with the inputParser class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `inputParser` class is not powerful enough to solve this problem on its own. You can use the `inputParser` to check each input individually, but you will have to do the more complicated processing yourself. Something like the following:

```
function out = createRVE(domain, distribution, varargin)
    inputs = parseInputs(domain, distribution, varargin{:});

    % rest of the function

end

function inputs = parseInputs(domain, distribution, varargin)
    VALID_DISTRIBUTION = {'uniform', 'hex'};
    parser = inputParser();
    parser.addRequired('domain', @(x) isnumeric(x) && isvector(x) && numel(x) == 4);
    parser.addRequired('distribution', @(x) ismember(x, VALID_DISTRIBUTION));
    % Here, we add the optional parameters with defaults set to NaN
    % That way we can check whether they were set
    parser.addParameter('grainCount', NaN, @(x) isscalar(x) && floor(x) == ceil(x));
    parser.addParameter('radius', NaN, @(x) isscalar(x) && isa(x, 'double'));
    parser.parse(domain, distribution, varargin{:})
    inputs = parser.Results;
    if ~isnan(inputs.radius) && strcmp(inputs.distribution, 'uniform')
        warning('radius is defined only for a hex distribution');
    end
    if ~isnan(inputs.grainCount) && strcmp(inputs.distribution, 'hex')
        warning('grainCount is defined only for a uniform distribution');
    end
end
```